# How to copy files into the app-specific files directory of a release app?

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I want to copy a file to the internal storage directory reserved for an application (not my application, I only have the apk) built in release mode. I thought of two solutions, but none of them actually work (note that rooting the phone is not an option):

- Directly copying the data to the internal storage folder of that app (not possible because the app was built in release mode).
- Installing another app in debug mode with the same ID as the original app, copying the file there then installing the original app. However, this does not work because the two apps have different signatures, and if I first uninstall the debug app android wipes its internal storage folder.

Is there any other way to do this? What I need is to somehow have that file end up in that app's internal storage.

Comment: If this is possible on a non-rooted phone, it would represent a substantial security flaw.

Comment: I understand it could be risky to allow an app to view another app's internal storage, but this risk is not there when an app is able to write (only write) to another app's specific files directory.

Comment: It is unclear what you consider to be apps internal storage.

Comment: @WaisKamal That's not true at all.  If you can write to another app's directory, you could overwrite a file and provide false data.  Or inject bad data into a db.  Or the app may process all files in a given directory, and by writing into that directory it could be processed and cause a host of security issues.  Write access to an app's directories is just as big a security issue as read access.

Comment: A lot of thanks for your info everyone. Sothis is not possible through Android. Is it possible to run the device's storage medium in other OS (windows for example) and do this (withour rooting the phone)?

Comment: @blackapps it is the same that the documentation considers as app's internal storage.

Comment: And you will not tell which path? You wanna send helpers to do the work?

Comment: @blackapps the path is not the same across all devices. On my device it is /data/data/[app_id]

Comment: And that path does not belong to your app but to a different app. But you want your app to copy files to that path. Well that will not go as your app has no access to another apps private paths. Has nothing to do with release mode. I dont understand why you mentioned release mode.

Comment: I want to copy the file myself, not enable my app to copy the file. If the app was in debug mode, I can copy the file via adb.